# Snowflake appending "_COL_0" when using COPY INTO with parquet

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet

My query runs like this:
Go to 2 different S3 buckets, do a join on the parquet files in those buckets, then copy the results to a new parquet file and copy into S3.

Im running into a strange issue where when I run a COPY INTO in Snowflake with parquet format, the parquet file created has an extra column, then converts the parquet I get from the SELECT/JOIN into a string. Also, the main select statement shows the correct object, I think its just the COPY INTO

Actual: `"_COL_0": "{\"room_ids\":[],\"food_ids\":[],\"uid\":\"abc123d\"}`

Expected: `{"room_ids":[],"food_ids":[],"uid":"abc123d"}`

Here is the query:

```
COPY INTO @S3_STAGE/new-data
FROM (
select *
  from @S3_STAGE/food
  (FILE_FORMAT => 'PARQ', pattern => '.*.parquet')
  where $1:uid in
   (select $1:uid from @S3_STAGE/rooms
   (FILE_FORMAT => 'PARQ', pattern => '.*.parquet')
   )
)
FILE_FORMAT = PARQ
```

A sample parquet would be like

```
{
  {"uid": "abc123d", "foods": ["banana", "apple", "orange"]},
  {"uid": "abc234d", "foods": ["banana", "apple", "grape"]},
  {"uid": "abc345d", "foods": ["banana", "grape", "peach"]}
}
```

Comment: can you share a sample parquet file that produces this problem?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa added example file. its a very basic parquet file

Comment: my biggest problem is the fact that the parquet file is changing the array of foods[] into a string like "foods": "[\"banana\", \"grape\", \"peach\"]"

Answer (score 0):

1. Try projecting the columns explicitly rather than using `*`.
2. Alias each column using quotes if you want the result to be lowercase
3. Set `header=true` in order to preserve column names and avoid the `_COL_n`

Docs:

[Unloading a Relational Table to Parquet with Multiple Columns](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-considerations.html#unloading-a-relational-table-to-parquet-with-multiple-columns)

[Transforming Data During a Load](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html)

```
COPY INTO @S3_STAGE/new-data
FROM (
select 
  $1:room_ids as "room_ids",
  $1:food_ids as "food_ids",
  $1:uid as "uid"
  from @S3_STAGE/food
  (FILE_FORMAT => 'PARQ', pattern => '.*.parquet')
  where $1:uid in
   (select $1:uid from @S3_STAGE/rooms
   (FILE_FORMAT => 'PARQ', pattern => '.*.parquet')
   )
)
HEADER=true
FILE_FORMAT = PARQ
```